# configuring gmail smtp in a contact form

Tags: php, email

This is the configuration of my contact form for the Gmail SMTP,

```
<Config>
        <smtp>
            <use>yes</use>
            <auth>no</auth>
            <secure>tls</secure>
            <host>smtp.gmail.com</host>
            <username>abc@gmail.com</username>
            <password>1234567</password>
            <port>465</port>
        </smtp>
        <charset>iso-8859-1</charset>
    </Config>
```

I've been trying for a while but I couldn't be able to send an email through the form, what am i possibly doing wrong ?

P.S: I am using Super Ajax Contact Form, and of course, i used my real email/password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auth` should be set to `yes`. See example here: http://www.globushotel.com/form/help.html